# Data table doesn't refresh

Tags: powerapp, sql, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app where on one screen I have a data table connected to a SQL server table, which pulls a list of values. When I select a value in that list, it's supposed to take me to another screen that runs a stored procedure, drops the results into a table, and displays the values from the table. Everything except "displays the values from the table" is working.

I know the stored procedure is running and dropping the results into the table, because I can see them when I query the database directly. But the data in the data table on the second screen doesn't change. In my `OnVisible` property for the screen I have `<flowname>.Run(variable, variable); Refresh(<tablename>)` but it isn't working as I hoped.

I tried moving both commands to the `OnSelect` of the first screen which navigates to the second, but I still get the old results in the data table.

Then I tried setting a timer so the data table didn't show until after the flow had run and after the table refresh, but that didn't work as I hoped either.

I don't have a ton of experience with PowerApps, so I suspect it's something I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the data source for your data table (`items` property of data table control)?

Comment: @GaneshSanap A sql table. The items property is `schema.table`.

Comment: Does `schema.table` updates when you refresh your data source on click of button.

Comment: @GaneshSanap In the `OnVisible` property for the screen that displays the results, I have `<flowname>.Run(variable, variable); Refresh(<tablename>)`.  The `OnSelect` property of the button on the previous screen navigates to the results screen.

Comment: Your question doesn't realy have any connection to SharePoint and would be better suited in a PowerApps site, where you can expect more PowerApps experience. We have some PowerApps know how here, but it's mainly about SharePoint.